# migrate the domain from joomla to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, migration

I have a website with the domain [www.dlsrci.org](http://dlsrci.org) which uses Joomla and is hosted by Hostgator.

Now the problem is that I want to make the same website using Wordpress with the same domain name `dlsrci.org`. How should I approach further with this process? After installing Wordpress, it's asking for the domain name and if I give the same domain name then there will be a conflict with Joomla and the Wordpress website and on the same side I cannot put the Joomla website down until the Wordpress website is totally completed.

Please help me in this regards.

Comment: You could put wordpress in a subfolder e.x `domain.com/wordpress` and once you complete development move it to root.

Comment: @emmanuel thanks a ton for giving the desired solution. :)

Comment: @emmanuel 'i did exactly what you told me to do, but now while moving the word press from sub folder to root, html and css files are missing and some of the links are showing 404 error.